# Panda Genetics on Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m playing on a peaceful realm with some friends. I tried to build a weak panda slime ball farm but having issues with the baby pandas.

I bred pandas until i had pairs of weak pandas to breed them again.
Looking at the wiki and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/358383/how-rare-are-brown-pandas) I expected to get a lot of weak pandas from breeding weak pandas (the wiki states, the weak gene is recessive and thus weak pandas need to have 2 weak genes). But I actually get all the pandas, including brown pandas, which would be astronomically unlikely when looking at the odds in the linked question.

Can anyone deny or confirm, that either
a) there are no genetics in panda breeding on bedrock
or
b) the weak gene isn’t recessive on bedrock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some extensive testing today, as there is no way on bedrock to check for hidden genes.
I am pretty sure, there is actually no genetics involved in panda breeding on bedrock. I crossbred weak pandas for almost 7 hours now and recorded every baby personality. there was no correlation between the outcome of the personalities to the parents at all. If the gene just wasn’t recessive (my first thought), there would be some sort of of hint at the hidden genes of the parents, but as I said – there was absolutely none.

The distribution of personalities from the babies is pretty close to the spawning chance for each personality...
So I’m assuming breeding pandas just spawns a baby with a random personality, independent of the parents.

Sadface.